# In StreamInsight, I am trying to walk through code

Tags: debugging, user-defined-functions, streaminsight

In StreamInsight 2.1, I am trying to use a user-defined function to extend functionality.  For now, all work is in IDE.

Segment in Stream processing

```
var foo = from ev in source
select new MyDataType
{
    NewRate = Parse(ev.NewValue, "New rate")
};
public static string Parse(string fromString, string pattern)
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

This is fine and it all runs correctly, but it won't let me step into the UDF with f11 or break point.  Is there an easy way of seeing the machination with the UDF?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer.  In reality I was just defining the declaration of the function, not the processing of the function.  It's not until foo is actually used that the breakpoint is hit.  This comes later with the binding

using (IDisposable proc = query.Bind(sink).Run("MyProcess"))

When this is done, I do actually hit my break point